# JSON error in javascript when using websockets

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

I seem to be overlooking an error in my code that I just can't figure out. I have read multiple online sources showing what the error can be, but I can't find it in my code.

I am using WebSockets to communicate between my front and backend, when sending data in JSON format from my front to backend, it works perfectly, but not the other way around.

In my code snippets, I replaced my data with dummy values to make it easier to see the error.

Backend:

> some_code.js

```
var msg = {"a": "a"};
Websocket.Send(msg);
```

> websocket.js

```
Websocket.Send = (msg) =>
{   
    Websocket.Socket.clients.forEach(function each(client) 
    {    
        client.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    });
}
```

Frontend:

> websocket.js

```
Socket.addEventListener("message", ({msg}) => 
{
    console.log(JSON.parse(msg));
});
```

Error:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A [`MessageEvent`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent) doesn’t have a `msg` property. Have you tried logging the value _before_ attempting to destructure and parse it?

Comment: You are trying to `JSON.parse(msg)` when `msg` is undefined. You will want to parse the `data` property on the `MessageEvent`.

`(evt) => JSON.parse(evt.data)`

Comment: @ Sebastian Simon Where would the incoming data from the backend be held then?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so changing the code of websocket.js to the following fixed it.

> websocket.js

```
Socket.addEventListener("message", ({data}) => 
{
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

So it seems that the WebSocket library requires the variable name holding the received data to be named "data".

Comment: You can rename this variable like this: `Socket.addEventListener("message", ({data: msg})`

Comment: No, `data` is not a “required” variable name; it’s the _property_ name on the `MessageEvent` object that you receive. As you can see in the documentation, such an object has the properties `data`, `origin`, `lastEventId`, `source`, `ports`, and a few others. There is no `msg` property, even if you named some other vaguely related thing somewhere else `msg`.